# How to embed $U(1)$ (or other groups) into a bigger group, using Dynkin diagrams

Tags: lie-algebras, dynkin-diagrams

I am trying to find the embedding and the branching rules for some group decompositions. For example, I consider $E_7$ and its maximally compact subgroup $SU(8)$ and I want to "see" how the Dynkin diagram of $E_7$ is modified to get $A_7$. I tried to take a linear combination of roots to produce $A_7$.

The problem is for an embedding like $SU(8) \supset SU(6) \times U(1)$. How do I get this?

Answer (score 2):

Since $SU(8)$ is a maximal regular subalgebra of $E_7$, you can identify it by looking at the extended Dynkin diagram.  This is the diagram you get by appending the lowest root to the simple roots that you have.  The $E_7$ Dynkin diagram looks like this: 
[image: $E_7$ diagram]

The extended diagram you get by appending the lowest root has an extra circle on the left side of the diagram:

[image: extended $E_7$]

Now you obtain the subalgebras by erasing one of the circles in the diagram, so to get $A_7$, you just erase the circle that is sticking up.  This means to get the roots of the $A_7$ subalgebra from the $E_7$ roots, you just take the six original simple roots that don't include the one sticking up, and add to it the lowest $E_7$ root.

This procedure will give you all the maximal regular subalgebras of a given Lie algebra.  Each diagram has a unique extended diagram from which you can construct these maximal regular subalgebras.  You can find the [extended diagrams here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram#Affine_Dynkin_diagrams).

The other example you asked about, $SU(8) \supset SU(7)\times U(1) $ (I'm doing $SU(7)$ instead of $SU(6)$, since it is the bigger subalgebra) simply comes from erasing one of the nodes of the $A_7$ diagram.  The resulting Dynkin diagram is $A_6$ which describes the $SU(7)$ factor, and then the node you erased is the $U(1)$ generator, which commutes with all elements of the $A_6$ algebra.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a question. When  I remove a node, this gives me the $U(1)$ (and not $SU(2)$) because $U(1)$ actually is the maximal torus in $SU(2)$ and only the commutant sub-algebras "survive" to this procedure?

Comment: @Oscar Maybe the way to think about it is that when you are erasing a node, you are reducing the dimension of the root vector space.  So you lose all the root vectors that had a component parallel to the root you erased.  However, as you said, the node you erased had a corresponding generator in the maximal torus, which is sitting at the origin in the root vector space (i.e. its weight is the zero vector).  So it can be included in the subspace, but will commute with everything else in the subalgebra that is left.